# Programmatically loading user control and accessing attributes

Tags: .net, attributes, controls, ascx

I have a defined a user control that looks like this at the top of the .ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ...  Description="Agreement" %>
```

How can I access this Description field programmatically, after dynamically loading the user control?  The following does NOT work:

```
string desc = ((CustomType)LoadControl("usercontrol.ascx")).Attributes["Description"];
```

It is loading the user control but there is nothing in the Attributes collection. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you try splitting that code out into two lines? line 1: `CustomType ct = (CustomType)LoadControl("usercontrol.ascx");` line 2: `string desc = ct.Attributes["Description"]`. And two other points: 1) what version of .NET are you using, 2) In which page lifecycle method are you attempting to do `LoadControl`?

Comment: I could split into 2 lines but I don't see how that would help. I'm using .NET 2.0  and I'm loading the control from the Page_Load of the parent .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b.aspx, Description is as follows:

> Provides a text description of the
>   control. This value is ignored by the
>   ASP.NET parser.

That being said, a `<%@` tag is an ASP.NET directive that tells ASP.NET how to compile your page.  It generally does not result in any object you can refer to in the code to access the details of that directive.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas of other ways to accomplish this? I just want to put some text in the .ascx markup that I can retrieve programmatically when I load the control.

Comment: How about a `Label` with `Visible="false"` and `Text` set to the string you want to read back?

Comment: Yeah  I could do something like that, I was just hoping for a more elegant way to give it a friendly title

Comment: You could make your own `Control` that has properties however you want, then put an instance of that `Control` on your page.

Comment: Yes, it is my own control (instance of my custom type) but I'm loading it dynamically, and I want to define the property value within the particular control itself. I've got it working by adding the property to the code page of the control, I just would prefer to be able to add it to the markup instead of hard-coding it in the code file.